# Find indexes of elements in list

Tags: scheme, racket

I can use findf to find elements in a list based on some procedure:

```
(define sl '("tester" "testing"  "other words" "for test of" ))
(findf (lambda (x) (string-contains? x "test")) sl)
```

Output:

```
'("tester" "testing" "for test of")
```

How can I get indexes of the elements which satisfy some procedure which returns true and false such as "string-contains?" above ?  I want have following output in above case:

```
'(0 1 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#lang racket

(define (find strings needle)
  (for/list ([s strings]
             [i (in-naturals)]
             #:when (string-contains? s needle))
    i))

(find '("tester" "testing"  "other words" "for test of")
      "test")
```

Comment: I want to have a function to which I can send any function, just as I can send any function to findf. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Change the argument `neeedle` to, say, `f`. Then replace the test `(string-contains? s needle)` with another that uses `f`.